# error in python for searchtweets to retrieve data

Tags: python, range

for some reason, I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-0cd9472f8df9> in <module>()
----> 1 [print(tweet.user_mentions[0].get('id')) for tweet in tweets]

<ipython-input-27-0cd9472f8df9> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [print(tweet.user_mentions[0].get('id')) for tweet in tweets]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am using searchtweets package and this is the code I am using to retrieve the mentions user id:

```
 for tweet in tweets: 
  print(tweet.user_mentions[0].get('id'))
```

It gives me the date until there is a null value

```
169686021
18120497
482708367
18120497
2227281840
482708367
33333620
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7f6c50e8ab0b> in <module>()
      1 for tweet in tweets:
----> 2   print(tweet.user_mentions[0].get('id'))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the issue is with tweet.user_mentions[0], because indexing[0] will throw an IndexError error if user_mentions list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is grabbing the first entry in the `user_mention` list object. Giving the documentation a quick look, I don't see that there's any requirement for `user_mention` to contain anything. Effectively, you're getting lucky before it finds one that is empty.

To get the first mention, if one exists, change your loop to:

```python
for tweet in tweets: 
  # if the user_mentions list is not empty, print the id of the first entry
  if tweet.user_mentions:
    print(tweet.user_mentions[0].get('id'))
```

Note: this is the "pythonic" way to check if the list is empty. You could also write this as `if len(tweet.user_mentions) > 0:`, though that will often throw linting errors.